# Lines not straight in ggplot polar plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hopefully you can help me out. I'm working on polar plots to show my data, but the arrows I'm plotting keep on being blurry/not smooth/straight. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Many thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/is4hp.png)

""

```
limit = 160
# polar plot
polar <- ggplot(data_polar, aes(x=angle, y=PEV))+
  coord_polar(start = 1.5*pi, direction=-1, clip="off")+
  geom_segment(aes(y=0, xend=angle, yend=PEV, color=electrode), 
               arrow=arrow(length = unit(0.02, "npc")), 
               size=1.1)+
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0, 360), breaks=c(0, 90, 180, 270), labels=c("         0\u00B0","90\u00B0\n\n", "180\u00B0            ", "\n\n270\u00B0"))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, limit), breaks=c(limit/4, limit/2, limit*0.75, limit))+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("LAN" = "red", 
                                "SAN"="green", 
                                "PAN"="blue", 
                                "LANPAN"="purple", 
                                "LANSAN"="brown"
                                )) +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(),
        legend.position="bottom",
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(size = 0.5), panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 1),
        axis.text.x = element_text( size=11, face="bold"), axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.text.y =element_blank(), axis.ticks.y =element_blank(), axis.title.y =element_blank())+
  labs(color = "Electrode(s)", title="Subject 2")+
  geom_text(x = 360-67.5, y = limit, label = limit, size = 3.5, color="black")+
  geom_text(x = 360-67.5, y = limit*0.25, label = limit*0.25, size = 3.5, color="black") +
  geom_text(x = 360-67.5, y = limit*0.5, label = limit*0.5, size = 3.5, color="black") +
  geom_text(x = 360-67.5, y = limit*0.75, label = limit*0.75, size = 3.5, color="black") +
  geom_text(x = 360-67.5, y = limit*1.3, label = "PEV\n(dps)", size = 2.5, color="grey")
```

""

Comment: This mostly seems like an anti-alias issue on the default windows graphics device. Have you tried other devices such as cairo or ragg?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! To be honest I'd never heard of it, but I looked it up and it works great! Many thanks!

Comment: [1/2] I agree with @teunbrand (to whom I always defer where ggplot2 is concerned :-), it seems an issue with aliasing. Another option to consider: **vector** versus **raster** images. For instance, most interactive viewing canvases in R are raster based, meaning if you "zoom in" you can see pixels and notches in lines such as in your image; this effect can be _reduced_ by expanding the dimensions of the image, but that is not always convenient and will increase image/file size, while never completely mitigating the problem.

Comment: [2/2] With vector-based formats (pdf, svg), this never happens: the file size is relatively invariant of intended dimensions, and one can zoom in to arbitrary levels without the issue of aliasing we see here. The biggest downside of using vector-based formats is that plots with _lots_ of points/lines make a much larger filesize and may take much longer to render and pan/zoom.